# Panel not working inside Do loop

Tags: gui-construction

If I have `Do[Interpretation[Pannel[...]]]`, the code **does nothing**.

How to fix it?

Below is the most simple example, I could think of and it **does not work**.

```
Do[
 var = vars[[i]];
 Interpretation[Panel[Grid[{
     {"ADD 1 TO?", SpanFromLeft},
     {ToString[var], InputField[Dynamic[var]]}
     }]],
  Print[var + 1]
  ],
 {i, Length[vars]}]
```

It should **open new panel for each variable in `vars`**. Each one of those panels should do following things:

- Ask user to input value of the variable.
- After inputting value print the inputed value+1.

And now to the real example:

First I defined function `ObrazecSez[sez_]` as followoing:

```
 ObrazecSez[sez_] := ToExpression[
   "Interpretation[\[IndentingNewLine]Panel[Grid[{{Style["
    <>
    "ToString["
    <>
    "VNESITE VREDNOSTI"
    <>
    "]"
    <>
    ",Bold],SpanFromLeft},"
    <>
    StringDrop[StringJoin[
      ("{" <> "ToString[" <> ToString[#] <> "]" <> 
          ",InputField[Dynamic[" <> ToString[#] <> "]]}" <> ",\n") & /@
        sez
      ], -2]
    <>
    "}]],"
    <>
    ToString[sez]
    <>
    "]"
   ];
```

sez is a list of variables. The function `ObrazecSez[sez_]` makes a panel appear, that asks user to assign values to variables in `sez`. The values are Then assigned and `sez` with assigned values is outputed. This **works**.

[image]

Then i have another function `Spremenljivke[enačba_]`:

```
Spremenljivke[enačba_] := 
 With[{globalQ = Context@# === "Global`" &}, DeleteDuplicates@Cases[
    enačba,
    _Symbol?globalQ, Infinity]]
```

`enačba` is equation. The function `Spremenljivke[enačba_]` outputs a list of variables in equation `enačba`. This also **works**.
[image]

Then I have a lot of code following. I wrote in `(**)`, what each part of code should do. This **does not work**.

```
konstantne = {};       
Nkonstantne = {};      
neodvisna = {};
Nneodvisna = {};
odvisna = {};
Nodvisna = {};
VseSpremenljivke = {};
NVseSpremenljivke = {};

Interpretation[
 Panel[
  Grid[{
    {Style["POROČILO", Bold], SpanFromLeft},
    {"ENAČBE ZA MERJENO:", InputField[Dynamic[enačbe]]}  
    (*enačbe is a list of equations inputed by the user*)
    }]
  ],
 
 Do[                (*for each i-th equation in enačbe*)
  Interpretation[
   Panel[
    Grid[{
      {Style[enačbe[[i]], Bold], SpanFromLeft},  (*shows i-
      th equation in a title*)
      
      {"NEODVISNA:", 
       InputField[
        Dynamic[neodvisnai]]},   (*user inputs one of the variables \
in i-th equation*)            
      {"ODVISNA", 
       InputField[
        Dynamic[odvisnai]]}                  (*user inputs another \
one of the variables in i-th equation*)
      }]
    ],
   VseSpremenljivkei = 
    Spremenljivke[enačbe[[i]]]; (*list of all variables in i-
   th equation*)
   konstantnei = 
    DeleteCases[DeleteCases[VseSpremenljivkei, odvisnai], 
     neodvisnai];(*list of all variables in i-
   th equation without odvisnai and neodvisnai*)
   AppendTo[neodvisna, neodvisnai];
   AppendTo[odvisna, odvisnai];
   AppendTo[VseSpremenljivke, VseSpremenljivkei];
   AppendTo[konstantne, konstantnei];
   
   NVseSpremenljivkei = 
    ObrazecSez[
     VseSpremenljivkei];(*asks user to assign values to all variables \
in VseSpremenljivkei*)
   AppendTo[NVseSpremenljivke, NVseSpremenljivkei];
   
   ]
  , {i, Length[enačbe]}];
 {VseSpremenljivke, NVseSpremenljivke, neodvisna, odvisna, 
  konstantne}] (*output*)
```

Comment: Interpretation creates an object. Your code creates 6 objects and throws them away. But you may e.g.  store the objects in a function  like e.g.: a[i]= Interpretation[... ] Then after your code run, you may say e.g. a[3] and you get the third object back.

Comment: Please do not add the [tag:bugs] tag to your own questions. See the tag description for an explanation.

Comment: There is no bug here. `Do` evaluates an expression multiple times. Evaluating `Panel` or `Interpretation` has no side effects (`Panels` does not *open* a panel, it doesn't *perfrom any action*, it merely formats in a certain way when displayed). Therefore, nothing happens. If you want to return the results, use `Table` instead of `Do`. If this doesn't help, please explain what you are trying to achieve in more detail.

Comment: It's also unclear to me what you are trying to achieve with `Interpretation[..., Print[...]]`. I suspect a misunderstanding about the purpose of `Interpretation`. This shows that the question should be clarified. BTW you did get a comment from Daniel above, but didn't address it. The best way to get answers is to engage, address comments, and ensure that the question is very clear. Setting bounties won't help an unclear question, and won't replace communication.

Comment: I just editid the question so that it's more accurate and clear now

Comment: You should look at DialogInput

Comment: I'm not quite sure why you're using `Interpretation`—`Interpretation[x,y]` is something which *creates inline code* that looks like/functions like `x`, and then evaluating that inline code with Shift+Enter causes `y` to be evaluated *in the place where the inline code is*. Is this indeed what you want it to do? If not, you might want something that performs actions "by itself" (that is, without it evaluating to something within some some larger piece of code, as Interpretation does); check out `DynamicWrapper, or...

Comment: ...consider using the second argument of `Dynamic` to produce "hidden" effects, as in `Slider[Dynamic[x, (Print["old: ",#2," | new: ",#1]; x = #1) &]]`, which will print the old and new value of `x` every time the slider updates it. Note that when using the second argument of dynamic, you must update the variables yourself in the function, e.g. how I included `x = #1`, so it can be a bit tricky.

Comment: Actually I'm doing GUI for the first time and when I opened GUI documentation (reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/GeneralizedInput.html), there were so many strange functions (just too much to learn, what each does(including Interpretation)). So the only thing, I could do was to just copy  things, that looked about right. This is why I used Interpretation[Pannel[...]]. Then I took a look at (https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/CreatingDialogBoxes.html), as suggested by -Jason B. That looks like it might just work (I haven't finished everything yet, but I'm close.)